# Powershell TestPath and GetADuser Issues based off current location

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm having issues with a set of scripts I am writing to create new Active Directory users. At this point I'm trying to test if a prospective account name is already in use, along with whether a folder with the same name exists. Below is an example of what I'm using:

```
$UserNameToCheck = 'TTesterson'

$SamTest = $null
$SamTest = Get-ADUser -filter {samAccountName -eq $UserNameToCheck} -Server XX-DC.domain.ca

$PathToTest = '\\FileServer\Users$\' + $UserNameToCheck
$FolderTest = Test-Path $PathToTest

if( ($SamTest -eq $null) -and ($FolderTest -eq $false) )
{#Set a flag here and do some stuff}
```

Here's the problem, when I run my script, I can't target a specific server (the -server parameter) unless I've set my current location to AD: Similarly, I can't get Test-Path to work unless I'm NOT set to be in AD: Would anyone be able to explain why this is happening, and what I could do apart from constantly setting my location back and forth between the two?

Thanks.

(Edited to change double quotes to single quotes on file path)

Comment: One problem that I can see right off the bat is that you either need to escape the $ in your string or use single quotes instead of double quotes when you build the string.

Comment: Do I? It's addressing a share that is using the $ character in it's share name, and seems to be working now with single or double quotes. So long as my current location is set to a network drive or a local drive, I can hit the network resource as it is written. It's only when my current directory is AD: that it fails.

That being said, best practices would probably say that whether it's working or not, I should be building it properly, so advice taken! (heh!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an explicit drive in your path (which you don't since it's a UNC), PowerShell will assume that it is a path in the current PSDrive/PSProvider.  To specify, prefix the path with `filesystem::`.

Like this:

```
$PathToTest = 'filesystem::\\FileServer\Users$\' + $UserNameToCheck
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains why I couldn't get Test-Path working. It still leaves me to wonder why Get-ADUser occasionally fails to accept the -server parameter when I'm not in AD:, but it solves it to the point where I can at least get this working.